# How do I fix Django changes made outside of my virtual environment?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and new to the virtualenv scene.

I have been working on a Django project for a couple of days and completely forgot to activate my venv on my second day.

I am using [this](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/installation/) tutorial to guide me and I have been working from within my activated environment up until [this](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_start_project/) point....

Is it enough to just re-run manage.py after activating my venv?

Comment: depends if you installed packages or not. But there's no harm in trying to run `manage.py runserver` and see what happens. If you get an error like 'module not found' then you'll have to re-install (pip install) it in your virtualenv

Comment: You should run your Django project from virtual environment and if some packages are missing you need to install them into virtual environment. I guess that's it.

Comment: @dirkgroten, yes, my changes are registering on my server just fine. Since I have not installed anything, I guess it means I will be fine running manage.py again. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Tino indeed, I actually made the initial installations (from the tutorial) from within the environment. The changes I made outside the environment are the app scripts and admin authentications so I guess I am okay since I did not install packages outside the environment. thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

**Activating a virtual environment**

Before you can start installing or using packages in your virtual environment you’ll need to activate it. Activating a virtual environment will put the virtual environment-specific python and pip executables into your shell’s PATH.

**On macOS and Linux:**

```
source env/bin/activate
```

**On Windows:**

```
.\env\Scripts\activate
```

You can confirm you’re in the virtual environment by checking the location of your Python interpreter, it should point to the env directory.

On macOS and Linux:

```
which python
.../env/bin/python
```

On Windows:

```
where python
.../env/bin/python.exe
```

**Leaving the virtual environment**

If you want to switch projects or otherwise leave your virtual environment, simply run:

```
deactivate
```

If you want to re-enter the virtual environment just follow the same instructions above about activating a virtual environment. There’s no need to re-create the virtual environment.

**For Django**

After active your virtual environment you need to run Django development server. To run the Django Development server go to manage.py directory.

**And run the following command:**

```
python manage.py runserver
```

And your Django Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: @Rakibul, thank you for the detailed explanation. It is my understanding that virtual environments are activated to accommodate compatibility in package installations. Therefore, other changes I made outside of my environment might not necessarily be affected so I am glad.  It helps to have the important commands in one place so appreciate it.